# Why Spring Data JPA's save() is slow when called on a single record vs calling it on a list of records?

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm experiencing a major time reduction when using `save` function from `SimpleJpaRepository` on a `single record vs calling save on a list of records`.

The loop below takes `10` times longer than the `list`.

```
    for (Record r : csvRecords) {
            myRepository.save(r);
    }
```

`myRepository` doesn't have any `@Transactional` annotations at all.
But the loop below is blazingly fast in comparison to the above.

```
List<Record> myArray = new ArrayList();
for (Record r : csvRecords) {
        myArray.add(r);
}
myRepository.save(myArray);
```

if we look at the `save` implementation from `SimpleJpaRepository`

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {

   List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

   if (entities == null) {
      return result;
   }

   for (S entity : entities) {
      result.add(save(entity));
   }

   return result;
}
```

This implementation just masks the single `save` operation so it shouldn't make any difference if I first store my data in a buffer or I call save on each of my record therefore the speed increase doesn't make any sense for me .

EDIT:
using the [docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.5.1.RELEA‌​SE/](http://%20docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.5.1.RELEA%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BSE/) version .

Comment: Are you sure that you're not using a subclass of `SimpleJpaRepository`, that overrides the `save(Iterable)` method with something more optimized?

Comment: In case of single 10 single calls to `save()` you are performing 10 transaction but only one if calling `save()` with a list of 10 records. That's probably the reason for your observation.

Comment: The JPA API has no such "save" method. Perhaps you mean "Spring Data JPA" which is NOT the JPA API.

Comment: @DN1 thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of a single entry you are opening 10 transactions - that need to be opened and closed; in the case of the `List` the `save(singleEntry)` (that is used inside `saveAll`) will re-use the already opened transaction, so it's a single one that is opened and closed. And btw if I re-call correctly its `saveAll(Iterable)` *not* `save(Iterable)`.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out ! https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.5.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html apparently I used an older version.

Comment: @Oleg ah! that makes sense.